# Reading mail from /var/spool/mail/root

Tags: linux, command-line-interface, email

I've tried using `mail` for reading the e-mail messages in /var/spool/mail/root, but it's really a pain.
I've read that `pine` is better, but it seems not to be available for my linux (CentOS 5.4 x86_64). At least nothing appears when I type `yum list pine`.

Do you know of any other command line utility to read mail from there?

Comment: Related: [Script Help - Parse /var/spool/mail/user](http://serverfault.com/q/169162/41258)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try `mutt`. Or `elm`. (Given that when you say command line utility you mean working in text mode.)

Edit: Even better, put an alias for root into `/etc/mail/aliases` to redirect root's mail to another account. Remember to run `newaliases` afterwards. This only works if you have a working MTA (Mail Transfer Agent) of course.

Comment: `mutt -f /var/spool/mail/root`

Answer (score 4):

Pine was replaced by [Alpine](https://www.washington.edu/alpine/) some time ago.

> Alpine is a fast, easy to use email client that is suitable for both the inexperienced email user as well as for the most demanding of power users. Alpine is based on the Pine® Message System, which was also developed at the University of Washington.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [sup](https://sup-heliotrope.github.io/). It's a curses mail client inspired in mutt and gmail, written in ruby and actively developed.

If you install ruby and rubygems, just `sudo gem install sup` should be enough to install it.