# Script Help - Parse /var/spool/mail/user

Tags: linux, email, scripting, sendmail

CentOS 5.x | SendMail

Hi guys,

Is there an easy way to retrieve individual messages from /var/spool/mail/? I have an idea for a really simple script and would like to check each individual message for something.

The scenario would be:

1) new email arrives in inbox.
2) Script checks for certain string. 
3) If string is found, script retrieves various header info and emails info to address.

I realize that a milter would probably be the way to go but I was hoping to find a way to do this with a shell script as I want to practice that. The problem is that I can't seem to find a way to parse or otherwise isolate the individual messages.  When I examine /var/spool/mail/, I see a big file with multiple messages and no unique delimiter between messages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you ignore simple shell scripts almost every single programming language has a library to parse a [mbox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mbox) formated mailbox.

- http://docs.python.org/library/mailbox.html
- http://search.cpan.org/~dcoppit/Mail-Mbox-MessageParser-1.5002/lib/Mail/Mbox/MessageParser/Perl.pm
- http://www.phpclasses.org/browse/file/3127.html

Of course if you look around you can also find lots of POP3 and IMAP client libraries as well.

You should also be able to use something like [procmail](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Procmail) or [maildrop](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maildrop) to filter your messages.

Comment: Cool. I was planning to learn python anyway... I guess I might as well do that now. 

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Classically you would do this kind of things when the mail is received, using an MDA such as procmail. If you already have a mailbox, procmail comes with `formail`(1) which lets you run a program on each mail in a mailbox and has facilities to filter and rewrite headers.